# How do I use data gathered from foreground service?

Tags: java

I am trying to program an app that gathers GPS locations in a foreground service, saves them in an arraylist and when the foreground service is "destroyed" the arraylist is sent over and used by another activity. So basically how can I use the data I gathered through my foreground service? Do I have to bind it? Is that efficient if I only need to send the data over one time? Thank you.

I am doing this in android studio*

I tried to create a new activity from the service and send it over that way but that is not allowed. I read about binding and tried it out but I am unsure if this is a good way to solve the issue.

Comment: Try out shared preferences.